# why is my string ( char array ) is not printing?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I try to execute a simple program in c++ and I am not able to get that result what should I do now I tried this code with different versions on gcc compiler in different platform.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
{
    int i,m,j;
   char a[10],b[10],temp;
    cout << " give the string " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    m=strlen(a);
    j=0;
   for(i=m;i>0;i--){
    b[j]=a[i];
    cout << " inloop "<<b;
     j++;
 }
cout << b << endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: There is no chance of getting an answer to this question as it stands because you do not say what the result you want is, and telepathy is hard.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to reverse a string. Use `std::string` and it has all the necessary functions for string operations.

Comment: "I am not able to get that result" - we're no fortune tellers. Tell us the expected result and the actual one, along with input you provide.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using C++ strings?

Comment: @Mahesh Any idea why an image of a paperclip came to my mind while reading your comment?

Comment: by `cout << " inloop "<<b` you probably mean `cout << " inloop "<<b[j]` and by `i=m;i>0` you probably mean `i=m-1;i>=0`...but without requirements noone can know what wou're trying to achieve

Comment: That is some of the least consistent indentation I've seen in code - it's almost like at every line you randomly select a number between 0 and 5 for the indentation.

Answer (score 6):

Everything in C is 0-indexed. `a[i]` at first iteration is `a[strlen(a)]` which is `\0`.

if your input is `bobo`, the contents of the array `a` will be

```
a[0] = 'b'
a[1] = 'o'
a[2] = 'b'
a[3] = 'o'
a[4] = '\0'
```

your loop starts from a[4] (because strlen(a) == 4), so your b string will be:

```
b[0] = '\0'
b[1] = 'o'
b[2] = 'b'
b[3] = 'o'
b[4] = 'b'
```

printing it will result in "" being printed.

Answer (score 1):

To correct your code.
You need to iterate from m-1 to 0. and add \0 at the end of the string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int i,m,j;
  char a[10],b[10],temp;
  cout << " give the string " << endl;
  cin >> a;
  cout << a;
  m=strlen(a);
  j=0;
  for(i=m-1;i>=0;i--){ // Iteration changed here 
    b[j]=a[i];
    cout << " inloop "<<b;
    j++;
  }
  b[j] = '\0'; // Add this line
  cout << endl << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works but why can't I just use cout b ( sorry I am putting this comment from cell phone)

Comment: @user2253623 you can do it. The problem is in the for statement. You are copying `'\0'` in `b[0]`.
`'\0'` is the string-terminating character.